# Mercurial ignores a file rename (changing case)

Tags: mercurial

I'm working with a project I inherited from a Windows guy. It's under Hg version control. It got some inconsistent filename convention which I'm trying to fix so I renamed a file named `jquery.fullpage.js` to `jquery.fullPage.js` (just uppercased "P") to adhere to the original author of that jQuery library.

However, **Hg doesn't detect the lowercase-uppercase change** as a rename or even as deleted/created file. As a result, I can't commit that change and push it live. It works locally but on the remote staging server where I pushed, it gives 404 errors. Apparently, the files on the remote weren't renamed to the uppercase P.

I know I can fix this by deleting the file, commit, restore the file and rename, commit again but that seems to be a crude way of fixing it.

How do I fix this?﻿

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a case folding problem. Try to rename the file through Mercurial: `hg rename jquery.fullpage.js jquery.fullPage.js`.

Comment: This worked. I'm not very happy with this solution. Though I have read more about the case-folding problem and it seems to be a problem with case-insensitive filesystems.

Comment: I used `mv` but it still didn’t cause the system I ran `pull -uv` on to rename it. Oh, I’m trying to rename a folder/directory which is addressed [by the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111220/429091).

Comment: What about a regex solution? lets say I changed many extension files from distinct folders ( all images )

Answer (score 17):

If you're renaming a file you are good to go with `hg rename` as already said.

However (at least on **Windows**), if you're renaming a **folder** then you can't rename it directly. The common workaround is to use an intermediate:

```
hg rename Foo tmp
hg rename tmp foo
```

Another workaround is using intermediate delete. But this is **discouraged** because you would lose the file history.

Comment: Do I need a commit between those two renames?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OS X and you're using HFS that is case-aware but not case-sensitive, then Hg (nor Git, as I found out) will pick up the change.  I use Linux and my co-worker uses OS X and we had a similar problem with Git.  Going through an intermediate rename is one workaround, or using an intermediate delete as you suggested.

I believe Jakub's suggestion of using hg itself to effect the rename will work, but I haven't tried it, since I don't have hg installed.

Comment: Indeed, I am on OSX. It doesn't detect the change. The remote staging server is on Linux so the staging server works alright.

Answer (score -1):

Also there is 
`hg rename --after oldFile newFile`
 if the change is already in place.

Comment: This did *not* work for me. Mercurial complains that newFile does not exist (even though it clearly does)

Comment: Make sure you wrote full path case sensitive.