# Mercurial rename(only case change) a directory with files inside it in single commit

Tags: mercurial, rename, tortoisehg

Problem: Existing folder '`Validator`' has 3 files inside it, if I want to rename it to '`validator`' (only case change). TortoiseHg is creating a *subdirectory* in `Validator` and moves 3 file inside it (`Validator/validator/<3 file>`).

How can I commit such rename in JUST 1 commit?

Workaround: Rename `Validator` to '`tempDir`', commit the change, rename '`tempDir`' back to `validator`, this works BUT in 2 commits to the repo which is not what I want.

Note: I use tortoiseHg to rename and not eclipse or Windows explorer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mercurial ignores a file rename (changing case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575401/mercurial-ignores-a-file-rename-changing-case)